# Why are these functions using %128?

Tags: function

I am looking at the following functions which (i) take a 7-bit number (up to 127) and add it to 256-bit number, starting 64 positions in from the right and (ii) read that 7-bit number given the 256-bit number.

My question is why these functions are using % 128. I've run a number of tests of these functions using different values, with and without the %128, and they always return the same thing whether I include % 128 or not. And also the most a 7-bit number can store is 127, so modding by 128 is always just gonna return that same number, so why do it?

```
 function addOptionRatio(
        uint256 self,
        uint256 _optionRatio
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            return self + (uint256(_optionRatio % 128) << (64));
        }
    }



function optionRatio(uint256 self) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            return uint256((self >> (64)) % 128);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation `a % b` returns the remainder of the integer division `a / b`. In your question `_optionRatio % 128` will be different than `_optionRatio` when `_optionRatio` is greater or equal to `128`.

For example when `_optionRatio = 128` then `_optionRatio % 128` will be zero.

You haven't provided enough code to determine if `% 128`  is redundant or not. If `_optionRatio` were a 7 bit value, for exampled declared as `uint7` then it will be redundant.